# Data value is rendering as 'name' prior to the data being loaded

Tags: javascript, ejs

See image below.

Upon search submission, the data should be rendering below the search bar, which is being loaded through ejs as follows:

```
<div class="data">
            <%= data %>
        </div>
```

The other day, this data was being loaded after hitting search, however, now when loading my local host, the word 'name' appears right away.

When I go into my source code on the webpage, it is showing as

```
<div class="data">
            name
        </div>
```

so this must be where this problem is coming from.
How can I stop the word `name` from rendering, and instead just load the data on form submit?

[image]

---

Edit:
Here is some backend code

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('index',{
      data: 'name'
  })
})

app.post('/', async(req, res) => {

  const whoissearch = new whoissearch()

  try {
      await whoissearch()

      const url = req.body

      let urlEncoded = decodeURIComponent(url.url);

      await whoissearch.init();
      const site = await whoissearch.open(urlEncoded)
      site.on('error', console.error) // catch the errors
      const results = await site.analyze()


      const data = JSON.stringify(results, null, 2)
      console.log(results.whois[0].name)

      await whoissearch.destroy()

      res.render('index', {
          data: data
      });
```

I've traced down the error to coming from these lines

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('index',{
      data: 'name'
  })
})
```

Comment: Could you share more code so we can find a better solution? Will the actual data replace 'name' once the data is available?

Comment: @10110 it seemed to go away after resetting the server. Not sure what happened....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical problem when dealing with asyncronous code and APIs. You shoud look into the concept called "conditional rendering" to deal with this.

I haven't worked with ejs in a while so sorry if the syntax is not correct.

Could you try:

```
<div class="data">
        <%= data !== 'name' ? data : '' %>
</div>
```

What you are seeing here is something that you could call "dynamic rendering with ternary operator.

Comment: Didn't seem to work, I am not super familiar with ejs either unfortunately...

Comment: Please share more code. Your question is almost perfect but I (we) need more context cause we're assuming stuff from your code because you're not sharing it!

Comment: I have updated to share where it is coming from, and my backend. Hoping you can take a look!

Comment: Note: The npm package is private

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Ok, I updated my this answer, please give it a shot but the idea behind it is something like: "If `data` is not equal to 'name' render it's value, otherwise don't". That's conditional rendering.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked! If you have the time, make sure to check [this](https://www.includehelp.com/node-js/ejs-if-else-statement-ejs-conditions.aspx) and [this](https://blog.joeandrieu.com/2013/10/16/how-to-conditionally-display-variables-with-ejs/) resources to learn a bit more about conditional rendering!

Answer (score 0):

Had to reset the server. It appears to have fixed itself.

Comment: Oh, bummer haha... Anyway, if you ever get this problem. Look into conditional rendering so you can prevent stuff you don't want from appearing, you can also replace the empty string (`''`) with a message like 'Loading...' or something like that. good luck

Comment: @10110 Now its back again. So conditional rendering? Not sure if this would be conditional rendering, as I just don't want anything to appear prior to the button being hit

Comment: Gotcha... where does the word 'name' come from? Is it a default value you're defining? If you could add a bit more code, maybe we can find a better solution :)

Comment: Updated the original post :)